# How to make an Android custom view that is compatible with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I have created a custom view that only extends the View class. The custom view works perfectly, except when being used inside a RecyclerView. This is the custom view:

```
public class KdaBar extends View {
    private int mKillCount, mDeathCount, mAssistCount;
    private int mKillColor, mDeathColor, mAssistColor;
    private int mViewWidth, mViewHeight;
    private Paint mKillBarPaint, mDeathBarPaint, mAssistBarPaint, mBgPaint;
    private float mKillPart, mDeathPart, mAssistPart;

    public KdaBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.KdaBar,
                0, 0);

        try {
            mKillCount = a.getInt(R.styleable.KdaBar_killCount, 0);
            mDeathCount = a.getInt(R.styleable.KdaBar_deathCount, 0);
            mAssistCount = a.getInt(R.styleable.KdaBar_assistCount, 0);

            mKillColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.KdaBar_killBarColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.kill_score_color));
            mDeathColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.KdaBar_deathBarColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.death_score_color));
            mAssistColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.KdaBar_assistBarColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.assist_score_color));
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        init();
    }

    public void setValues(int killCount, int deathCount, int assistCount) {

        mKillCount = killCount;
        mDeathCount = deathCount;
        mAssistCount = assistCount;

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, mViewWidth, mViewHeight, mBgPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mKillPart+mDeathPart, 0f, mKillPart+mDeathPart+mAssistPart, mViewHeight, mAssistBarPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mKillPart, 0f, mKillPart+mDeathPart, mViewHeight, mDeathBarPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, mKillPart, mViewHeight, mKillBarPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld){
        super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

        mViewWidth = xNew;
        mViewHeight = yNew;

        float total = mKillCount + mDeathCount + mAssistCount;
        mKillPart = (mKillCount/total) * mViewWidth;
        mDeathPart = (mDeathCount/total) * mViewWidth;
        mAssistPart = (mAssistCount/total) * mViewWidth;
    }

    private void init() {
        mKillBarPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mKillBarPaint.setColor(mKillColor);

        mDeathBarPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mDeathBarPaint.setColor(mDeathColor);

        mAssistBarPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mAssistBarPaint.setColor(mAssistColor);

        mBgPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mBgPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.transparent));
    }
}
```

The linked image is what the custom view currently looks like (The custom view is the rectangle above the numbers at the center) https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHnaF.jpg

The numbers below that bar represents their value (They are color-coded in case you haven't noticed). It is obvious that a value of zero on the first item shouldn't show a blue bar on the custom view. Weird, I know.

The method below is where the values are set (it is inside the RecyclerView.Adapter<>):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MatchHistory.Match item = mDataset.get(position);
    MatchHistory.MatchPlayer[] players = item.getPlayers();

    for(MatchHistory.MatchPlayer player: players) {
        int steamId32 = (int) Long.parseLong(mCurrentPlayer.getSteamId());
        if (steamId32 == player.getAccountId()) {
            mCurrentMatchPlayer = player;
        }
    }
    ...
    holder.mKdaBar.setValues(mCurrentMatchPlayer.getKills(), mCurrentMatchPlayer.getDeaths(), mCurrentMatchPlayer.getAssists());
    ...
}
```

This is the onCreateViewHolder:

```
@Override
public MatchesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_match_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```

and the ViewHolder class:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    KdaBar mKdaBar;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        ...
        mKdaBar = (KdaBar) v.findViewById(R.id.kda_bar);
        ...
    }
}
```

I think it is useful to note that the dataset being used by the adapter changes the position of the items from time to time (since it is being fetched all at the same time but are inserted so that the dataset is ordered). I almost forgot that I also tested not changing the positions of the items inside the dataset, but still there aren't any good results. If you checked the image, you can see that there are other info inside the items and I am 100% sure those are all correct with the exception of the data in the custom view.

I am thinking that I am forgetting some methods that must be overridden but I already saw a lot of tutorials and none of them mentioned about this issue. Looking forward to solving this issue. TIA!

Comment: Can you share more code? Is the custom view just the canvas drawing? How do you set mCurrentMatchPlayer? What does the onCreateViewHolder work

Comment: @napkinsterror Yes the custom view is just the canvas drawing, for the mCurrentMatchPlayer and onCreateViewHolder, check out the edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the dataset but with my understanding of how RecyclerView works underneath (just as [napkinsterror](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2406824/napkinsterror) have mentioned in his answer).

This it the revised custom view:

```
public class KdaBar extends View {
    private int mKillCount, mDeathCount, mAssistCount;
    private int mKillColor, mDeathColor, mAssistColor;
    private int mViewWidth, mViewHeight;
    private Paint mKillBarPaint, mDeathBarPaint, mAssistBarPaint, mBgPaint;
    private float mKillPart, mDeathPart, mAssistPart;

    public KdaBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.KdaBar,
                0, 0);

        try {
            mKillCount = a.getInt(R.styleable.KdaBar_killCount, 0);
            mDeathCount = a.getInt(R.styleable.KdaBar_deathCount, 0);
            mAssistCount = a.getInt(R.styleable.KdaBar_assistCount, 0);

            mKillColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.KdaBar_killBarColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.kill_score_color));
            mDeathColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.KdaBar_deathBarColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.death_score_color));
            mAssistColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.KdaBar_assistBarColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.assist_score_color));
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        init();
    }

    public void setValues(int killCount, int deathCount, int assistCount) {
        mKillCount = killCount;
        mDeathCount = deathCount;
        mAssistCount = assistCount;
    }

    private void calculatePartitions() {
        float total = mKillCount + mDeathCount + mAssistCount;
        mKillPart = (mKillCount/total) * mViewWidth;
        mDeathPart = (mDeathCount/total) * mViewWidth;
        mAssistPart = (mAssistCount/total) * mViewWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        calculatePartitions();

        canvas.drawRect(mKillPart+mDeathPart, 0f, mKillPart+mDeathPart+mAssistPart, mViewHeight, mAssistBarPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mKillPart, 0f, mKillPart+mDeathPart, mViewHeight, mDeathBarPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, mKillPart, mViewHeight, mKillBarPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld){
        super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

        mViewWidth = xNew;
        mViewHeight = yNew;
    }

    private void init() {
        mKillBarPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mKillBarPaint.setColor(mKillColor);

        mDeathBarPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mDeathBarPaint.setColor(mDeathColor);

        mAssistBarPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mAssistBarPaint.setColor(mAssistColor);

        mBgPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mBgPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.transparent));
    }
}
```

These are the changes I made:

1. Removed the `invalidate()` call from inside the `setValues()` since the `onDraw()` callback is invoked when the parent adds a view.
2. Moved the assignment of `mKillPart`, `mDeathPart`, and `mAssistPart` to `calculatePartitions()` which is, in turn, called inside `onDraw()`. This is because the values needed for the calculation are asssured to be complete inside `onDraw()`. This will be explained below.

This is what I've gathered from Mr. napkinsterror's answer:

When the LayoutManager asks the RecyclerView for a view, ultimately, the `onBindViewHolder()` method is called. Within that method, data is bound to the views, thus `setValues()` is called.

The view is returned to the LayoutManager, which will then add the item back to the RecyclerView. This event will trigger `onSizeChanged()` because the dimensions of the view are not known yet. That's where the `mViewWidth` and `mViewHeight` are retrieved. At this point, all the necessary values for `calculatePartitions()` are complete.

`onDraw()` is also called because the parent just added an item (check this [image](https://codentrick.com/content/images/2015/07/android_view_lifecycle.png)). `calculatePartitions()` is called inside `onDraw()` and the view will be drawn on the canvas without any problem.

The reason I get wrong values before is because I do the `calculatePartitions()` inside `onSizeChanged()` which is very, very wrong since `mViewWidth` and `mViewHeight` are yet to be known.

I will mark this as the answer but many thanks to mr. napkinsterror for providing resources so that I can research in the right direction. :)

Comment: Very nicely done, and glad you answered it yourself. I felt like my 'answer' was not an answer, but just a couple of pointers and debugging hints. I did not know everything about `onSizeChanged()` and `onDraw()`. Glad you investigated it and we both learned it, and most of all, your code is working!

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty hard to tell what is going on exactly especially if this code is working elsewhere, but I'll take a couple guesses.

The main things I noticed:

1. **Comparing int from long** where numbers are dangerously close to max
2. Calling **Invalidate from a View inside a RecyclerView** (especially onBindView)

**Issue 1**

In your picture, I'm guessing you are the steamId which are the numbers on the bottom left corner of each RecyclerView's view holder, for example: '2563966339'. You should know that "usually" in Android, **Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647**. This pretty much means you should use long or things won't be equal when you think they are... *(so maybe the boxes are being drawn correctly, but you just don't think the steamId at position 0 is the guy you think?!?!).*

(If you want to learn more about it just looked up signed vs usigned bytes for int and long).

So you might have to change some code, but I recommend using long or Long. Two of Many Possibilities Below

*Example 1*

```
long steamId32 = Long.parseLong(mCurrentPlayer.getSteamId());
if (steamId32 == player.getAccountId()) {
    mCurrentMatchPlayer = player;
}
```

*Example 2*

```
Long steamId32 = mCurrentPlayer.getSteamId();
if (steamId32.equals(player.getAccountId()) {
    mCurrentMatchPlayer = player;
}
```

**Issue 2:**

A lack of understanding of how RecyclerView works might be causing some problems. In onBindView, you should setup and draw the view as much as possible (without calling `invalidate()`). This is because RecyclerView is meant to handle all 'recycling'. So you invalidate() call might be causing some strange problems.

I know that onDraw() isn't normally called every time a view is bound, but only upon creation with RecyclerView. This would explain why it worked elsewhere!

### Summary and Analysis:

**Number 1:**

I would call (inside `onBindView` before `setValues`)

`Log.d("Whatever", "At position: " + position + " we have " + <steamId> + <kills> + <other desired info>)`.

After you scroll up and down you will see the person on the top and what values are being called and see if it is a problem mentioned in #1 or a problem with your position. If the person should have `0`, then let position 0 show 0 kills.

This could also point out one of these problems that I didn't think were as likely, but definitely possible:

I still don't know what `mCurrentPlayer` is exactly which could cause a problem. Also, if you need to update a 'item' in the adapter simply call `mAdapter.updateItemAt(position)` from the Activity/Fragment with recyclerView. If you have to move it call `mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPos, toPos)`. All these mean that maybe things aren't what you think when onBindView is being called.

**Number 2:**

I would recommend putting Log statements also in `onDraw()` to see if you know when it is **ACTUALLY** being called, and not just expect it after `invalidate()`. Most likely `invaidate()` is being *queued* by the main thread / recycler view until it decides it wantes to call `onDraw()`.

*(Because it already `created/drew` the item in `onCreateView()`)*

You might be surprised by what RecyclerView, LayoutManager, and the Adapter do and how they call the view methods. (You might also just want to put Log statements in `onBindView` and `onCreateView` to understand the whole process with `onDraw()`).

#### Understanding RecyclerView (and it's parts)

**Videos to Learn Basics:**

- [RecyclerView ins and outs - Google I/O 2016](https://youtu.be/LqBlYJTfLP4?t=17m36s)
- [RecyclerView Animations and Behind the Scenes (Android Dev Summit
  2015)](https://youtu.be/imsr8NrIAMs?t=3m37s)

**And for the readers, Android documentation provided this summary:**

```
Adapter: A subclass of RecyclerView.Adapter responsible for providing views that represent items in a data set.
Position: The position of a data item within an Adapter.
Index: The index of an attached child view as used in a call to getChildAt(int). Contrast with Position.
Binding: The process of preparing a child view to display data corresponding to a position within the adapter.
Recycle (view): A view previously used to display data for a specific adapter position may be placed in a cache for later reuse to display the same type of data again later. This can drastically improve performance by skipping initial layout inflation or construction.
Scrap (view): A child view that has entered into a temporarily detached state during layout. Scrap views may be reused without becoming fully detached from the parent RecyclerView, either unmodified if no rebinding is required or modified by the adapter if the view was considered dirty.
Dirty (view): A child view that must be rebound by the adapter before being displayed.
```

- [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)
- [RecyclerView.ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html)
- [RecyclerView.LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html)
- [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

Comment: 1. Casting the SteamId into integer from long is intended because the desired value is contained in the lowest 32 bits of the number, but I agree that this is somehow unsafe, I will look into this. Other than that I am sure that the values are correct and are at the position they needed to be.


2. Almost half of the things you said regarding how RecyclerView works etc. are quite new to me. Thanks for these tips, I am definitely going to try these. Will update if there are any progress/improvements.

Also, I'm gonna mark this as the answer if it actually works. Thank you kind sir :)

Comment: Updated to make it more clear for both Number 1 and Number 2. Definitely read how `onBindView` and `onCreateView` work. Also, you might want to see if you can find some other example of someone else drawing on the canvas inside a recyclerview. I have a feeling it will not be calling `invalidate()`. Good luck.